# Responsive Design: how to have text input and button stay 100% width of parent

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Very simple question... I'm hacking it right now with floated percentages (but I know that there has to be a better solution) please see my photo as an example to go by. I want to have the parent stay 100% in width and the search box be an automatic width that always stays next to the search button, and I want the search button to be able to grow as wide as it wants to (depending on the text inside of it/padding).

[image]

Comment: if you are using media query breakpoints, rather than a fluid layout, just set the widths explicitly in the media queries

Comment: Do you mean like so? http://jsfiddle.net/27M3Q/

Comment: For this particular instance I need this to be fluid (We will have over 50 languages go inside this button for localization so it needs to be able for its width to be automatic with padding)..and No, not like that @Sven , that's the method I'm currently using. The problem with that is the button is a percentage (I'm trying to allow the button to be as wide as the word inside it and allow the search field to be 100% next to the button).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### UPDATE (The Flexbox Way!)

The proper way to achieve this now is with Flexbox!

**CSS "Flexbox" Way** (https://jsfiddle.net/1jxkyLdv/)

```
    /* CSS
    **************************************************************************/

    /* Reset */
    * { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    body { margin: 1rem; }
    h2 { margin: 2rem 0 0; }


    /* Flexbox Example */
    .flexbox { display: flex; }
    .flexbox .stretch { flex: 1; }
    .flexbox .normal { flex: 0; margin: 0 0 0 1rem; }
    .flexbox div input { padding: .5em 1em; width: 100%; }
    .flexbox div button { padding: .5em 1em; white-space: nowrap; }



    <!-- HTML ------------------------------------------------------------------->

    <h1>Flexbox Way!</h1>

    <h2>Short Word</h2>
    <section class="flexbox">
            <div class="stretch">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
            </div>
            <div class="normal">
                <button>Search</button>
            </div>
    </section>

    <h2>Long Word</h2>
    <section class="flexbox">
            <div class="stretch">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
            </div>
            <div class="normal">
                <button>Super Long Word For Search Button With Flexbox!</button>
            </div>
    </section>
```

---

### THE OLD WAY

I despise using tables or using css to make divs act like tables), But here's the other way.

**CSS "Table-Cell" Way** (http://jsfiddle.net/eUhTM/3/)

```
        * { box-sizing: border-box; }

        section { width: 100%; display: table; padding: 1em 0 0; }
        div { display: table-cell; width: 100%; }
        input { width: 100%; padding: .5em 1em; }
        button { color: black; padding: .5em 1em; white-space: nowrap; margin: 0 0 0 1em; }

        <h1>Short Word</h1>
        <section>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button>Search</button>
                </div>
        </section>
```

**SOLUTION**

The main trick is to make the section a "display: table;" and the divs inside "display: table-cell;", you're input "width: 100%" and you're button "white-space: nowrap".

I'm still interested in solutions though!

Thank you everyone for your great answers.

Answer (score 5):

**Correct answer from MrRioku in the comments**

http://jsfiddle.net/eUhTM/3/

**My original answer**

http://jsfiddle.net/eUhTM/

This will probably be downvoted to oblivion for obvious reasons but what about doing this:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100%;">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search" style="width:100%;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I used inline CSS for simplified viewing :)

Comment: haha... I won't down vote you cuz you called yourself out... but dude. . . c'mon!! not semantic and it doesn't meet what i said at all..

Comment: @MrRioku haha I appreciate it. I played around with it on JSFiddle and I think my update will meet your expectations (minus the semantics) lol http://jsfiddle.net/eUhTM/

Comment: hey MonkeyZeus, I actually used a bit of your technique! haha.. but I made it with divs instead.. have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/eUhTM/3/

Comment: @MrRioku That's pretty sweet, learn something new everyday! I was honestly too lazy to mess with the `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;` styles. I will link your JSFiddle so that people can stumble upon the proper way lol

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not 100% sure this is the best way but it seems like the best I've came across so far

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed a bit tricky, especially if you do not know the width of the button in advance. You could off course go for a js solution, which should be fairly straightforward, but I prefer sticking to css as much as possible.

I did come up with a solution that works in your layout:

```html
<div class='searchBox'>
    <input type='text' placeholder='search...'/>
    <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

```css
.searchBox {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
}
input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}
button {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #555;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border: none;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 9px;
}
button::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    top: 0px;
    left: -10px;
    width: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
}
```

and a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VhZS5/

Not the cleanest solution ever, but it should be cross (modern) browser (the border-box may require some prefixing), is semantically correct, and it doesn't use tables.

Note that I positioned the button absolute on top of the input field. Then I used a ::before on the button to cover up the input box slightly and give the impression of some spacing between the input and the button.

Let me know if you want me to explain further.

Comment: I understand it, but its still a bit hacky,,, (like you said: the :before basically hides the input and creates a false border for it), http://jsfiddle.net/VhZS5/2/   Given both of your answers I've came up with an okay solution: http://jsfiddle.net/eUhTM/3/